VBA Regex pattern
I'm having some data appears to be like this and got this in CSV file
1305-0023, "4. Appropriate_icf for you version embarrasing version O1_01_SEZ02_9-03, 29-Nov-2023", "Trialinning", "da-3aff-41fe-8292-28f03", "AMERICA", "Initiated", "SEZ6", 2024-07-22T20:46:13.364843Z, "01bf9039-d66a-470b-a403-b7d63c8271ec", "Upversion and downversion", "In Process by Sponsor", 2023-12-052024-09-09y35346282828, 400, "BRB BRB Approval Letter [Site]", "tehdueuehjjkksjbbcgdh-dheyeyehhehe-ebhdbhdhjdjdd", "Ongoing", NULL, 2024-09-09y35346282828

Here the data present in between "" are text and without are other fields.
I need to split the data and needs to put it in columns in the excel
Please provide me a solution to split the data accordingly.
I tried to split using "," but there is "," present in between "" so the data is not splitting correctly and getting False results.

This question is similar to: Regex to split a CSV. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@trincot: That is for ASP?

Here is a solution using RegEx. I have commented the code so you should not have a problem understanding it. Here I am showing how to work with 1 string. This can easily be modified for a whole file. I also added a blank space to the RawData string for testing purpose.
RawData = "1305-0023,"""", ""4.......
Is this what you want?
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    '~~> Change this to relevant worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    '~~> Sample String
    Dim RawData As String
    RawData = "1305-0023,"""", ""4. Appropriate_icf for you version embarrasing version O1_01_SEZ02_9-03, 29-Nov-2023"", ""Trialinning"", ""da-3aff-41fe-8292-28f03"", ""AMERICA"", ""Initiated"", ""SEZ6"", 2024-07-22T20:46:13.364843Z, ""01bf9039-d66a-470b-a403-b7d63c8271ec"", ""Upversion and downversion"", ""In Process by Sponsor"", 2023-12-052024-09-09y35346282828, 400, ""BRB BRB Approval Letter [Site]"", ""tehdueuehjjkksjbbcgdh-dheyeyehhehe-ebhdbhdhjdjdd"", ""Ongoing"", NULL, 2024-09-09y35346282828"
    
    Dim ObjRegex As Object
    Dim ObjMatches As Object
    Dim ObjMatch As Object
    
    Dim Result As String
    Dim Rw As Long: Rw = 1
    Dim Col As Long: Col = 1

    '~~> Create the Regex object
    Set ObjRegex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    
    '~~> Regex pattern to handle quotes and commas
    ObjRegex.Pattern = """([^""]|"""")*""|[^,""]+"
    ObjRegex.Global = True

    '~~> Execute the regex on our raw data
    Set ObjMatches = ObjRegex.Execute(RawData)

    '~~> Loop through each match and process it
    For Each ObjMatch In ObjMatches
        Result = Trim(ObjMatch.Value)
        
        '~~> Process only if result is not empty
        If Result <> "" Then
            '~~> Remove surrounding quotes if they exist
            If Left(Result, 1) = """" And Right(Result, 1) = """" Then
                '~~> Remove surrounding quotes and replace any "" inside with a single quote
                Result = Mid(Result, 2, Len(Result) - 2)
                Result = Replace(Result, """""", """")
            End If
            '~~> Write to worksheet
            ws.Cells(Rw, Col).Value = Result
            Col = Col + 1
        End If
    Next ObjMatch
End Sub

Output


Parse Text Line
Function
Function ParsedTextLineToArray( _
    ByVal TextLine As String, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnDelimiter As String = ",") _
As Variant
    Const QUOTE_DELIMITER As String = """"

    Dim cLenI As Long: cLenI = Len(ColumnDelimiter) - 1
    
    Dim qSplit() As String: qSplit = Split(TextLine, QUOTE_DELIMITER)
    
    Dim qLimit As Long: qLimit = UBound(qSplit)
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim q As Long, n As Long, c As Long, cStart As Long
    Dim cSplit() As String, cText As String, qText As String
    Dim WasDoubleQuoted As Boolean, IsFirstDone As Boolean
    
    For q = 0 To qLimit
        qText = qSplit(q)
        If WasDoubleQuoted Then
            n = n + 1
            dict(n) = qText
            WasDoubleQuoted = False
        Else
            If qText = ColumnDelimiter Then
                WasDoubleQuoted = True
            Else
                If InStrRev(qText, ColumnDelimiter) = Len(qText) - cLenI Then
                    WasDoubleQuoted = True
                End If
                cSplit = Split(qText, ColumnDelimiter)
                For c = cStart To UBound(cSplit) + WasDoubleQuoted
                    n = n + 1
                    dict(n) = cSplit(c)
                Next c
            End If
        End If
        If Not IsFirstDone Then
            cStart = 1
            IsFirstDone = True
        End If
    Next q
    
    ParsedTextLineToArray = dict.Items
    
End Function

Test
Sub Test()

    Const TEST_STRING As String = "1305-0023, " _
        & """4. Appropriate_icf for you version embarrasing version " _
        & "O1_01_SEZ02_9-03, 29-Nov-2023"", " _
        & """Trialinning"", " _
        & """da-3aff-41fe-8292-28f03"", " _
        & """AMERICA"", " _
        & """Initiated"", " _
        & """SEZ6"", " _
        & "2024-07-22T20:46:13.364843Z, " _
        & """01bf9039-d66a-470b-a403-b7d63c8271ec"", " _
        & """Upversion and downversion"", " _
        & """In Process by Sponsor"", " _
        & "2023-12-052024-09-09y35346282828, " _
        & "400, " _
        & """BRB BRB Approval Letter [Site]"", " _
        & """tehdueuehjjkksjbbcgdh-dheyeyehhehe-ebhdbhdhjdjdd"", " _
        & """Ongoing"", " _
        & "NULL, " _
        & "2024-09-09y35346282828"
    
    Debug.Print TEST_STRING & vbLf & vbLf
    Debug.Print Join(ParsedTextLineToArray(TEST_STRING, ", "), vbLf)

End Sub

Test Result
1305-0023
4. Appropriate_icf for you version embarrasing version O1_01_SEZ02_9-03, 29-Nov-2023
Trialinning
da-3aff-41fe-8292-28f03
AMERICA
Initiated
SEZ6
2024-07-22T20:46:13.364843Z
01bf9039-d66a-470b-a403-b7d63c8271ec
Upversion and downversion
In Process by Sponsor
2023-12-052024-09-09y35346282828
400
BRB BRB Approval Letter [Site]
tehdueuehjjkksjbbcgdh-dheyeyehhehe-ebhdbhdhjdjdd
Ongoing
NULL
2024-09-09y35346282828


Nicely done. There is one small tweak you will have to do' Handle empty string. For example  I added an extra comma before the double quote in Const TEST_STRING As String = "1305-0023, ," _

@SiddharthRout Thanks. I'm not sure if that string is 'valid', IMO 'valid' could be e.g.  "1305-0023, , " with a trailing space.

What I mean is consider this small string in a csv file. When you open it in notepad, it will look like this Sample,,"This is 1, 2, 3". When you open it in Excel, this will be shown in 3 columns. In your TEST_STRING, if you add two consecutive ,, then your code doesn't recognise that empty string.

Oh wait.. I understood where the issue is... To test it with a csv file, we need to remove the space after the comma . Debug.Print Join(ParsedTextLineToArray(TEST_STRING, ","), vbLf).or simply not pass it as it is optional. Nicely done once again!

I am not sure that I correctly understood what you need, so I will try showing to ways:

Splitting the string by comma even if it exists inside the strings between double quotes, as I could see in another answers. The next function does not need any iteration:

Function SplitLongStringByComma(TString As String) As Variant 'split Private Function SplitLongStringByComma(TString As String, Sep As String) As Variant 'split without doouble quotes, INCLUDING comma inside strings
    Dim arrQuot: arrQuot = Split(TString, """")
    SplitLongStringByComma = Split(Join(arrQuot, ""), Sep)
End Function

It can be tested using the next Sub. But take care, the string you show uses ", " as separator and it is more probable to have a CSV file using "," as separator and you need to use the appropriate one:
Sub testSplitLongStringByComma()
 Dim x As String, y As String, arrSpl
    'separator is ", " (as in your question sample)
    x = "1305-0023, ""4. Appropriate_icf for you version embarrasing version O1_01_SEZ02_9-03, 29-Nov-2023"", ""Trialinning""" & _
        ", ""da-3aff-41fe-8292-28f03"", ""AMERICA"", ""Initiated"", ""SEZ6"", 2024-07-22T20:46:13.364843Z, ""01bf9039-d66a-470b-a403-b7d63c8271ec""" & _
        ", ""Upversion and downversion"", ""In Process by Sponsor"", 2023-12-052024-09-09y35346282828, 400, ""BRB BRB Approval Letter [Site]""" & _
        ", ""tehdueuehjjkksjbbcgdh-dheyeyehhehe-ebhdbhdhjdjdd"", ""Ongoing"", NULL, 2024-09-09y35346282828"
        
    'separator is "," (as it should be in a CSV comma delimited)
    y = "1305-0023,""4. Appropriate_icf for you version embarrasing version O1_01_SEZ02_9-03, 29-Nov-2023"",""Trialinning""" & _
        ",""da-3aff-41fe-8292-28f03"",""AMERICA"",""Initiated"",""SEZ6"",2024-07-22T20:46:13.364843Z,""01bf9039-d66a-470b-a403-b7d63c8271ec""" & _
        ",""Upversion and downversion"",""In Process by Sponsor"",2023-12-052024-09-09y35346282828,400,""BRB BRB Approval Letter [Site]""" & _
        ",""tehdueuehjjkksjbbcgdh-dheyeyehhehe-ebhdbhdhjdjdd"",""Ongoing"",NULL,2024-09-09y35346282828"
        
 arrSpl = SplitLongStringByComma(x, ", ")
 Debug.Print Join(arrSpl, vbLf) 'just to see the returned array in Immediate Window (Ctrl + G, being in VBE)
 
 Debug.Print "______________________________________"
 arrSpl = SplitLongStringByComma(y, ",")
 Debug.Print Join(arrSpl, vbLf) 'just to see the returned array in Immediate Window (Ctrl + G, being in VBE)
End Sub

After processing of the respective string, it returns in Immediate Window a string like this:
1305-0023
4. Appropriate_icf for you version embarrasing version O1_01_SEZ02_9-03
29-Nov-2023
Trialinning
da-3aff-41fe-8292-28f03
AMERICA
Initiated
SEZ6
2024-07-22T20:46:13.364843Z
01bf9039-d66a-470b-a403-b7d63c8271ec
Upversion and downversion
In Process by Sponsor
2023-12-052024-09-09y35346282828
400
BRB BRB Approval Letter [Site]
tehdueuehjjkksjbbcgdh-dheyeyehhehe-ebhdbhdhjdjdd
Ongoing
NULL
2024-09-09y35346282828


The version I think is the needed one **keeping comma existing inside the strings (between double quotes). Please, try using the next function:

Private Function SplitLongStringKeepCommaInStrings(TString As String, Sep As String) As Variant 'split without doouble quotes, EXCLUDING comma inside strings
    Dim arrQuot: arrQuot = Split(TString, """") 'split the string by double quotes and place it in an array

    TString = VBA.Replace(Join(arrQuot, "|"), Sep & "|", Chr(222)) 'use Chr(222) as future separtor for the joined array (an unusual character...)
    TString = VBA.Replace(VBA.Replace(TString, "|" & Chr(222), Chr(222)), "|", Chr(222)) 'also replace "|" & Chr(222) and then "|" with Chr(222)
    
    Dim arr, i As Long: arr = Split(TString, Chr(222)) 'obtain the final array to be processed in order to keep ", " only in strings between double quotes
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        If Left(arr(i), Len(Sep)) = Sep Then                            'if not a former string between double quotes:
            arr(i) = VBA.Replace(Mid(arr(i), 3), Sep, Chr(222))  'eliminate Sep prefix and replace Sep with
                                                                  'Chr(222), to be used as separator for the joined array
        End If
    Next i
    
    SplitLongStringKeepCommaInStrings = Split(Join(arr, Chr(222)), Chr(222))
End Function

It can be tested using the next Sub:
Sub testSplitLongStringKeepCommaInStrings()
 Dim x As String, y As String, arrSpl
 x = "1305-0023, ""4. Appropriate_icf for you version embarrasing version O1_01_SEZ02_9-03, 29-Nov-2023"", ""Trialinning""" & _
     ", ""da-3aff-41fe-8292-28f03"", ""AMERICA"", ""Initiated"", ""SEZ6"", 2024-07-22T20:46:13.364843Z, ""01bf9039-d66a-470b-a403-b7d63c8271ec""" & _
     ", ""Upversion and downversion"", ""In Process by Sponsor"", 2023-12-052024-09-09y35346282828, 400, ""BRB BRB Approval Letter [Site]""" & _
     ", ""tehdueuehjjkksjbbcgdh-dheyeyehhehe-ebhdbhdhjdjdd"", ""Ongoing"", NULL, 2024-09-09y35346282828"
     
  'Debug.Print x 'uncomment to see the string in Immediate Window (to check it is the one written in the question)...
  y = "1305-0023,""4. Appropriate_icf for you version embarrasing version O1_01_SEZ02_9-03, 29-Nov-2023"",""Trialinning""" & _
      ",""da-3aff-41fe-8292-28f03"",""AMERICA"",""Initiated"",""SEZ6"",2024-07-22T20:46:13.364843Z,""01bf9039-d66a-470b-a403-b7d63c8271ec""" & _
      ",""Upversion and downversion"",""In Process by Sponsor"",2023-12-052024-09-09y35346282828,400,""BRB BRB Approval Letter [Site]""" & _
      ",""tehdueuehjjkksjbbcgdh-dheyeyehhehe-ebhdbhdhjdjdd"",""Ongoing"",NULL,2024-09-09y35346282828"
      
  arrSpl = SplitLongStringKeepCommaInStrings(x, ", ")
   Debug.Print Join(arrSpl, vbLf) 'to visually see the returned array elements (easily to be dropped in sheet)
  
   Debug.Print "______________________________________"
  arrSpl = SplitLongStringKeepCommaInStrings(y, ",")
   Debug.Print Join(arrSpl, vbLf) 'to visually see the returned array elements (easily to be dropped in sheet)
End Sub

It will return the next string in Immediate Window:
1305-0023
4. Appropriate_icf for you version embarrasing version O1_01_SEZ02_9-03, 29-Nov-2023
Trialinning
da-3aff-41fe-8292-28f03
AMERICA
Initiated
SEZ6
2024-07-22T20:46:13.364843Z
01bf9039-d66a-470b-a403-b7d63c8271ec
Upversion and downversion
In Process by Sponsor
2023-12-052024-09-09y35346282828
400
BRB BRB Approval Letter [Site]
tehdueuehjjkksjbbcgdh-dheyeyehhehe-ebhdbhdhjdjdd
Ongoing
NULL
2024-09-09y35346282828

If needed, I can supply a piece of code able to split the CSV file by rows, process each row, place processed rows in a 2D array and drop its content, at once, in an Excel sheet. But if so, I think this must be the object of a new question...
Please, send some feedback after testing it and do not hesitate to ask for clarifications if something even commented is not so clear.

Your problem is that your line is NOT splitting on comma, rather it is splitting on comma-space sequences.
One solution is to

Remove the space after each comma
Then split on the comma with " specified as the text delimiter
Finally, replace the space after the remaining commas

However, as @SiddharthRout points out, this will add spaces after the commas within the quoted strings whether or not there was a space initially.
Since this might be an issue, I will delete my VBA solution and just recommend the Power Query solution.
A simple method is to use Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac):
Data => Get and Transform Data => From Text/CSV
At the window that opens after you select Import

In the Delimiter box, select Custom and then enter , , ie: comma space
Then, depending on if more processing is needed, select either Load or Transform

Ron, if I am not wrong, if there is no space after the comma then wouldn't your method add a space? For example "The total amount is $10,000" will become "The total amount is $10, 000"

@SiddharthRout The VBA solution would. But if that is an issue, although it can be cured in VBA, I would recommend using the Power Query solution, where you can more easily define the delimiter and thereby have the text qualifier properly recognized. Thanks for pointing that out.

Assuming no nested quotes in input.
If you have access to REGEXEXTRACT Function - Microsoft Support,
=TOCOL(
    LET(
        in, A2,
        regex, "(?:("".*?"")|(.*?)),",
        matches, REGEXEXTRACT(IF(RIGHT(in) <> ",", in & ",", in), regex, 1, 1),
        commaRemoved, LEFT(matches, LEN(matches) - 1),
        quotesRemoved, SUBSTITUTE(commaRemoved, """", ""),
        TRIM(quotesRemoved)
    )
)



With VBA function as UDF (Windows Only)
Option Explicit

Function extractCSV(strInput As String) As String()
    
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim reMatches As Object
    Dim reMatch As Object
    Dim matches() As String
    
    With regEx
        .Pattern = "(?:("".*?"")|(.*?)),"
        .Global = True
    End With

    If Right(strInput, 1) <> "," Then
        strInput = strInput & ","
    End If
    
    Set reMatches = regEx.Execute(strInput)
    ReDim matches(reMatches.Count - 1) As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    i = 0
    For Each reMatch In reMatches
        matches(i) = reMatch.Value
        matches(i) = Replace(matches(i), """", "")
        matches(i) = Trim(Left(matches(i), Len(matches(i)) - 1))
        i = i + 1
    Next
    
    extractCSV = matches

    Set regEx = Nothing
    
End Function


